# Check if folder exists and if so add "New Folder 2"

Tags: java, ajax

I have a web application that I inherited. I am new to Java so don't beat me up too bad. I have the following method to add new folders to an attachment page. User can create new folders on the page and rename, but how do check to see if a "New Folder" already exists and if so create "New Folder (2)" or "New Folder (3)" etc...

Here is my method from my attachments servlet:

```
  protected void newFolderAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, User user, String folderId) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
                IOException {
    String key = request.getParameter("key");
    String value = request.getParameter("value");
    Attachment parent = AttachmentRepository.read(UUID.fromString(key));
    String path = parent.getPath();

    logger.debug("newFolder: key=" + key + " value=" + value + " path=" + path);
    if (AttachmentRepository.read(path + "New Folder/") == null) {
        long size = 0L;
        boolean isFolder = true;
        boolean isPicture = false;
        UUID attachmentId = UUID.randomUUID();
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentId, UUID.fromString(folderId), user.getUnitId(), UUID.fromString("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"), path + "New Folder/", size, isFolder, isPicture,
                        "", "0", "0", user.getName(), new Date());
        AttachmentRepository.add(attachment);

        File directory = new File(Settings.instance().getAttachmentsDir() + "/" + attachment.getPath());
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

    Attachment rootAttachment = AttachmentRepository.read(folderId + "/");
    writeJsonAttachmentsTree(response, user, request.getRequestURI(), rootAttachment);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no custom built-in function in Java that create for you directory if the desired name already exists, You should implement one by Yourself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File folderPath = new File("c:\\New Folder");

    // Check whatever folderPath exists
    System.out.println(folderPath.getPath() + " is directory ? " + folderPath.isDirectory());

    // Create new folder
    File folderCreated = createFolder(folderPath);
    System.out.println("The new directory path is: " + folderCreated.getPath());

    // Check whatever folderPath exists
    System.out.println(folderCreated.getPath() + " is directory ? " + folderCreated.isDirectory());
}

public static File createFolder(File path) {
    File pathNum = new File(path.getPath());
    String num = "";
    int i = 1;
    do {
        pathNum = new File(path.getPath() + num);
        num = "(" + ++i + ")";
    } while (!pathNum.mkdir());
    return pathNum;
}
```